# ClassCastException when filling TableView with data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am learning JavaFX and using it with JFoenix.
I have a tableView with two columns.
This is my code to fill my tableView with data.

```
@FXML
private JFXTreeTableView vocabularyTableView;
@FXML
private JFXTreeTableColumn<String, String> motherLanguageColumn;
@FXML
private JFXTreeTableColumn<String, String> foreignLanguageColumn;
```

In my method i call this but I get an Exception.

```
vocabularyTableView.getColumns().addAll(vocabulary.getTreeMap().keySet());

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase
```

What can I do to make it work and why does this throw an Exception?

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Furthermore using `String` as the type parameter of the tableview is often a bad idea. I'm not sure why you want a `TreeTableView` for vocabliary either...

Comment: Is SimpleStringProperty better?

Comment: I'd use `TableView<Map.Entry<String, String>>` or some custom class containing the values for both columns.

Comment: Note that the `TreeTableView.columns` list contains `TreeTableColumn`s. Probably this list is filled with your columns when the fxml is loaded. The only reason the compiler doesn't complain about your assignment is that you're using raw types. (If you use `JFXTreeTableView<String>` and use return type  `Map<String, *>` for `getTreeMap`. For this reason you should avoid using raw types).